# Can you explain my this doubt in the article "Will O’ The Wisp"?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, formality

[Source](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/toi-editorials/will-o-the-wisp-techno-animism-gets-a-global-facelift-with-pokemon-go/)

> Even the office – **because see**, hovering over your colleague’s head is a Pikachu or Charmander or Sandshrew or Jigglypuff.

Is the bold part grammatical and informal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is grammatical. **see** is an imperative, like "Look!", though the punctuation doesn't make this clear.  *Even the office (is exciting) because  --look!-- hovering over your colleague's head is ...*